# How to select an element using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

Given the following XML, I want to get the value "0123456" for `Name="Cat"`:

```
xml.xpath '//Custom[Name="Cat"]'
```

Gives me the first custom, which is correct, but I only want the "Value" not the entire Custom node.

```
<body>
  <Custom>
    <count>1</count>
    <Name>Cat</Name>
    <Value>0123456</Value>
  </Custom>
  <Custom>
    <count>2</count>
    <Name>Dog</Name>
    <Value>9876543</Value>
  </Custom>
<body>
```

Answer (score 2):

> I only want the "Value" not the entire Custom node.

So just go on writing the path:

```
//Custom[Name="Cat"]/Value
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use CSS selectors over XPath, for readability, as usually CSS contains less visual noise:

require 'nokogiri'

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<body>
  <Custom>
    <count>1</count>
    <Name>Cat</Name>
    <Value>0123456</Value>
  </Custom>
  <Custom>
    <count>2</count>
    <Name>Dog</Name>
    <Value>9876543</Value>
  </Custom>
<body>
EOT

foo = doc.search('name:contains("Cat")').map{ |node|
  node.next_element.text
}

foo # => ["0123456"]
```

This works because Nokogiri contains some of the jQuery CSS extensions, resulting in some useful additions.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value element text you need to set the xpath as below:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<body>
  <Custom>
    <count>1</count>
    <Name>Cat</Name>
    <Value>0123456</Value>
  </Custom>
  <Custom>
    <count>2</count>
    <Name>Dog</Name>
    <Value>9876543</Value>
  </Custom>
<body>
EOT

val=doc.xpath("//Custom[Name='Cat']/Value").text()
```

val => "0123456"